# Как убрать ошибку Error: «Load failed» при загрузке фотографии в supabase в Next js приложении?

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, next.js

В моем next.js приложении я загружаю фото из формы в облачное хранилище supabase. Я не могу избавиться от ошибки:
`[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Load failed`

При этом файл в supabase не загружается.

Через консоль я проверил, что image - это File object. Вот мой код, реализацию я взял из документации:

```
import * as Form from "@radix-ui/react-form";
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

const supabase = createClient(
  "url",
  "api-key",
);

export default function Warehouses() {

  async function uploadImage(e) {
    const image = e.files[0];

    const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
      .from("images")
      .upload("/", image);

    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    uploadImage(event.target.images);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <Form.Root className="FormRoot" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <Form.Field className="FormField" name="images">
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "baseline",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
              }}
            >
              <Form.Label className="FormLabel">
                Upload Images
              </Form.Label>
            </div>
            <Form.Control asChild>
              <input
                type="file"
                id="images"
                name="images"
                multiple
              />
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Field>

          <Form.Submit asChild>
            <Button>Create</Button>
          </Form.Submit>
        </Form.Root>
    </div>
  );
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?